# Is the heat ball really a ball?

Tags: heat-equation, spheres

Is the [heat ball](https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2014/10/17/heat-ball-and-heat-sphere-mean-value-property/) really a ball?

That is,

consider the heat ball set for $n=2$, then one gets points $(y,s) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^3$.

Do these points also satisfy an equation similar to the $\mathbb{R}^2$ ball:

$$x^2+y^2 \leq r^2$$

?

Also, I'm not entirely sure about how to interpret $t$ for a ball. I mean, what does one need $t$ for in a ball? Or $s$ for that matter?

Comment: Are you referring to the book on PDEs by Craig Evans? There he speaks of "heat ball" but that's not a ball, geometrically, it is a kind of "oval" in space-time.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The def. for heat ball is given in the link I provided.

Comment: @kimchilover Can you elaborate?

Comment: I misread your link.  Sorry.  It describes some set in $(x,y,s)$ space.  Slices determined by fixed values of $x$ are closed disks, but the overall shape is more complicated.

Comment: @kimchilover What's $s$ to be honest?

Comment: The "heat ball" of that link comes from Evans's book. As I said, that's not a true ball. Consult the book, it has some pictures of the heat ball also. There is also some motivation on why he chose this terminology.

Comment: It is the $s$ that appears in the first displayed formula in your link.  What does it *mean* or what is it *for*: I don't know.